# Spring Webflux error handling in RouterFunction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

I am a newbie in Spring gateway cloud (Spring Reactor). I would like to implement aggregation layer, which will download data from two microservices, like real api-gateway.
As I understand in Spring Cloud Gateway it need to be in reactive way implemented.

I found RouterFunction to create a gateway endpoint to implement POST to one of microservices. It works, but when microservices return BAD_STATUS or etc. Then response from my spring gateway is only 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, but I would like to have full message.

```
@Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> createNodes(TokenFilter tokenFilter, NodesHandler nodesHandler) {

    return RouterFunctions.route()
        .POST("/nodeNew", nodesHandler::createNodes)
        .filter(tokenFilter)
        .filter(dataNotFoundToBadRequest())
        .build();
  }
```

And I have handler (Now is quite primitive, I am learning webflux)

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createNodes(ServerRequest request) {


    return request.bodyToMono(RestNodeCreate.class)
        .flatMap(newNodeCreate -> {
          if (newNodeCreate.getAccessMethod().equals("TCPIP")) {
            return oldCatalog.createNode(Mono.just(newNodeCreate), getTokenFromRequest(request))
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                  System.out.println("OLD RESPONSE ");
                  return Mono.error(throwable));
                });
          } else {
            return builNodesToNewCatalog(Mono.just(newNodeCreate))
                .flatMap(newNodeCreate1 -> newCatalog.createNode(Mono.just(newNodeCreate1)))
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                  System.out.println("NEW RESPONSE ");
                  return Mono.error(throwable);
                });
          }
        })
        .flatMap(o -> ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just(o), Object.class));
}
```

And two services newCatalog, and oldCatalog with WebClient post request to particular microservices with method:

```
public Mono<RestNodeCreate> createNode(Mono<RestNodeCreate> node, String token) {
    return webClient
        .post()
        .uri("/nodes")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token)
        .body(node, RestNodeCreate.class)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
            response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class).flatMap(s -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException(s))))
        .bodyToMono(RestNodeCreate.class);
  }
```

Is it a way if Exception is thrown in webClient request to forward statusCode, message and etc to response from RouterFunction to have standarized error handler with response etc ?

```
{
   "timestamp": "forwarded from webclient response",
   "statuscode": "forwarded from webclient response", 
   "message": "forwarded from webclient response"
}
```

Is in spring-cloud-gateway possible to write it with blocking RestTemplate and synchronus @RestController ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for that:

```
import static org.springframework.boot.web.error.ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.EXCEPTION;
import static org.springframework.boot.web.error.ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.MESSAGE;

import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.boot.web.error.ErrorAttributeOptions;
import org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.error.DefaultErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.error.ErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest;

@Configuration
public class ErrorAttributesConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
    return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {

      @Override
      public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(ServerRequest request, ErrorAttributeOptions options) {
        return super.getErrorAttributes(request, options.including(MESSAGE, EXCEPTION));
      }
    };
  }
}
```